# Access to Tor anywhere

Tags: censorship, development

I develop a software that will necessarily connect to Tor but I'm looking for a solution where Tor is blocked (else, my software would be useless in countries like China for example) how I could do that ?

Comment: You'll have to use a bridge then.

Comment: Could you please specify what your software is doing? There are different ways to get past censorship. If you specify what your software is doing it might be easier to find the right way to access bridges. For example would it be okay if your software required a gmail account? That would possibly allow you to get access to bridges. Maybe it would even be possible to create an own pluggable transport or based on the way you plan to distribute your software even come with predefined bridges (probably with you running your own bridges for example on EC2)

Answer (score 1):

You could run [Bridges in the cloud](https://cloud.torproject.org/) and (if that is feasible) deliver different bridge configurations to different people.